# tenses when using 'imagine' to describe an imaginary situation

Tags: conditionals

I know how to use conditional tenses like this:

> If all these drivers **were made** redundant by autonomous cars, the
> unemployment rates in these countries **would** rise significantly.

But what about when using "imagine"? I know the 'imagine' sentence should use the simple present. But what about the second sentence. Should I use the conditional tense "would" in the second sentence?

> Imagine all these drivers **are made** redundant by autonomous cars. That
> **would/will raise** the unemployment rates in these countries
> significantly.

(I dreamed up these sentences.)

Comment: I have voted to close this question as off topic because it amounts to a request for proofreading. If there is more detail to what you want to know than Which form is correct?—like what you know about the forms, why you think one might be better, and what research you have already done—then you should add it. Furthermore, what  leads you to believe that the after-*imagine* version is idiomatic?

Comment: I think it's up to you whether you treat the "Imagine..." part as just another way of saying "What would it be like if...?", or whether you choose to go on by describing the imaginary scenario.

Comment: No, you don't have to use the present tense after imagine.  Why do you think that?

Comment: Both of these tenses are acceptable. They both omit an understood antecedent. "[If that were true,] that would raise [...]," vs "[If that happens,] that will raise [...]."

Comment: While you could say "Imagine [they] *are*," I'd argue that it would still be better to use the conditional, "Imagine [they] *were* made redundant...." The use of simple present with "imagine" is a bit of an informal usage; while standard, it's maybe not the most "correct," and IMO following sentences should still take conditional tense.

Comment: I could easily imagine something like "Imagine I'm your boss. What would I say?", and it would be perfectly idiomatic, though not formal. Even in formal writing I might write "Imagine a world in which the U.N. does not exist. Such a world *would* be chaotic." I don't feel that my use of the simple present in "does not" is *wrong*... but I might have been just as likely to choose "did not."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we would normally use the present tense: "Imagine all these drivers are ..." The future is possible, "Imagine all these drivers will be ...", but it sounds funny to me. I can't think of a rule it violates, but my intuition says no.

Either way, you'd use "would be" because you are talking about a conditional result. If X happens, then Y would happen. Note this has nothing to do with whether you think the prediction is accurate. You say "would" whether you believe it or not. If you want to express doubt, you could add extra words, like "some predict that the unemployment rate would .." etc.